# Auto increment conditional formatting formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which has two columns with a percentage value in each:

[image]

I would like every cell in the B column to be highlighted red if it is greater than the corresponding cell in the A column.

I have used the conditional formatting formula in cell B2:

```
=B2>A2
```

When copying down this conditional formatting formula into the rest of the cells in the B column, the formula does not auto increment. The expected behavior is that it would auto increment. E.g. in cell B3 the formula would auto increment to:

```
=B3>A3
```

When adding the formatting, I highlighted the whole B column rather than just the cell B2. I have also ensured the whole range is selected in the 'manage rules' section:

[image]

Comment: Use the applies to to include the full column.

Comment: Select the *entire* range of data from B2 down.. and then create the conditional formatting rule.

Comment: See updated OP.

Comment: Following the suggestions that both you made didn't have any affect. The conditional formatting formula stays as =B2>A2 for the whole of the B column rather than auto incrementing

Comment: The rule in the rule manager will not change depending on which cell you are choosing.  It is based on the upper left cell of the applies to, always.  It will though as you can see do the iteration when applied.

Comment: Right I see. That is somewhat misleading as the rule manager states 'show formatting rules for: current selection'

Comment: But that is the rule.  The rule for that cell includes the applies to: not just the formula.